# ASP.NET with AngularJS - Does not go to different view

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, redirect, post

I'm having issues with moving from index to another view. I would like to take user's input from index view and then create a second view based on user's input in index.

Here is a snippet of javascript portion where I used $http to post the data. The rigInfoModel matches a model in the backend and it was able to pass all information successfully:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        angular.module('bonus', ['ngRoute']).controller('rigController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http)
        {
            $scope.rigInfoModel = {
                payPeriods: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.payPeriods)),
                payPeriodID: $scope.payPeriod["Value"],
                supervisors: $scope.supervisors,
                profileID: $scope.supervisor["Value"],
                rigs: $scope.rigs

            };

            $scope.submit = function() {   
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url:"/",
                    data: $scope.rigInfoModel,
                });            
            };     

        }]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/About.cshtml'
                });
        }]);

</script>
```

The info gets pass to the controller to the following function:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(bonusSetup model)
       {
             @todo
             return View("SecondView", model);
        }
```

Here I expected to go to SecondView, but nothing happens. I use a regular form with ng-submit to post the data. When I change the form to

```
@html(beginform())
```

The redirect to second view works, but I'm not sure how to post data from angular model with it.

```
<div ng-app="bonus" ng-controller="rigController as rig">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">

        <label>Pay Period: &nbsp;</label><select ng-model="payPeriod" ng-options="p.Text for p in payPeriods"></select>
        <label>Supervisor: &nbsp;</label><select ng-model="supervisor" ng-options="s.Text for s in supervisors"></select>

        <div ng-repeat="rigName in rigs | limitTo:numOfRigNames">
            <input type="text" ng-model="rigName.name" placeholder="Enter Rig Name" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add Rig</button>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to approach this.

The first way is to use angular as a single page application, this is more common use of angular. In this style we don't need much of the views from ASP, we just need the data. So except for index, all other actions are changed from `ActionResult` to `JsonResult` and let angular handles the page routing independently according to data returned.

The second way is give up angular SAP feature and initialize it every page. This works when you are trying to use angular on specific pages only on an existing ASP website. In this way you still change `ActionResult` to `JsonResult`, and pass the next controller path in the JSON. Then angular can do a redirect to that page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've converted the application to SAP. Kinda odd that I'm not using any models from MVC but it worked out.